# How do I find answers with the maximum upvotes?

Tags: support, search, up-votes

How do I find in Stack Overflow, regardless of the question, the answers with the maximum upvotes? I just want to read the best answers posted in the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/561/top-10-answers

as commented below, you will probably want to filter further by interesting tags to get information of any value.

unfortunately there is currently no direct correlation of this query in the API.

when/if this does get implemented, an up-to-the-minute view of 'guru answers' to questions of interest will be possible.

Comment: And predictable, most of them are fluff...

Comment: @dmc - right you are. you need to be specific with tags to get any intelligible results

Comment: @SkySanders This no longer works; update?

Answer (score 1):

You can run/create a query at the [Stack Exchange Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/).